# Images over background image

Tags: html, css, image

I need help and I did not found any proper answer so far. I want to make background image on my website that is full width and height and responsive to any resolution and it is ok but problem is when I put other images ( I have 7 images over background img ). I place them and set with media query for every resolution and it is ok only when is fullscreen but when I watch regularly with address bar and bookmark bar in my browser it all messes around and even my background picture is not full width and height anymore. Sorry for bad English.

**CSS for body:**

```
  body {
    background-image: url('images/background1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then I put my images and with margin - left, right, bottom, top place them for different screen resolution in media query.

Do I need to set proper position to images or something else? Please give me a hint.

Edit:

[This is what I get in fullscreen and it is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5ZD1.jpg)

[But this is when is not fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eledw.jpg)

All are images except strips, those are part of background image.
Images have only margin style, nothing else. They are in divs with float style.

Comment: The code you provided is not sufficient to reproduce your problem. Please provide more (including HTML) or share screenshots of current behaviour and desired outcome.

Comment: Try setting your background-size to 'cover' instead of 100% 100%. You might also want to make a codepen/fiddle of your work so we can see an example of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make background images responsive is this:

```
img{
  background-image: url('.../your-image.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It is ok for fullscreen or without images but when I put images and it is not fulscreen ( with adress bar or bookmark bar) my background picture is smaller and images  are like in second screenshot from my first post.